# How to Draw inspo hover effect in JS or in css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to Drawing spots effect on image which highlights the elements on image on hover on spots and also need to show a line which connected with element after hover on different spots show on image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3e6b.png)

Comment: Have a go yourself and if still stuck put your code into the question with a description of what isn’t working. One way to do this is to place the points on the image at their % x and y positions so it is responsive. The second part of your question about lines is not comprehensible, please rephrase.

Comment: please show us your code. Also you probably might want to look at embedding SVG into HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.dome {
                background: url(https://www.zdnet.com/a/img/resize/ba1b1ab92085d777ab5e313b34c66a94b7aa1236/2023/06/05/79a43eb8-ce38-488c-8cc0-e04699aaca7f/bing.jpg?auto=webp&width=1280);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                background-size: cover;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
/*          overflow: hidden;*/
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            animation: pulses 2s infinite;
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon > img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index: 1;
            position: inherit;
            transition: .5s;
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon:hover > img {
            scale: 1.2;
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon:hover:after{
            opacity: 1;
            width: 210px;
            
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            height: 2px;
            background: #ffd503;
            opacity: 0;
            
        }
        
        

        .dome > .dome-icon:nth-child(1):after,
        .dome > .dome-icon:nth-child(2):after{
            left: 42px;
        }

        .dome > .dome-icon:nth-child(1) {
            transform: translate(-113px, 61px);
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon:nth-child(2) {
            transform: translate(-120px, 132px);
        }

        .dome > .dome-icon:nth-child(1):after {
            top: 50%;
        }
        .dome > .dome-icon:nth-child(2):after {
            rotate: -10deg;
            top: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="dome">
    <div class="dome-icon"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3135/3135715.png"></div>
    <div class="dome-icon"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3135/3135715.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> First thing is to add a coords on image by using area tag in a **map**.
> The **area** tag defines an area inside an image **map**. **Area** elements are always nested inside a **map** tag.
> Visit link: [area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

If you not satisfy with this solution then second option is to use transform in css and also add some js for proper solution. also clarify if you need something like this: [video link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/20938350?key=d7a143a5591ecb57ec56df5243f608d1)

Comment: I think the second option seems easy and closer to my needs. Can you generate a code for me...